# Создать картинку с определенным словом в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Приветствую.

Интересует, с помощью каких инструментов реализировать такое:

Пользователь вводит в консоле слово, а на выходе получает картинку в виде белого фона с черным текстом, текст = слово, которое ввел пользователь.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: С помощью Pillow.

Comment: Спасибо большое.